# vaidation_data should be a tuple in keras fit_generator

Tags: python, keras, training-data, batchsize

I am trying to override the `keras.util.Sequence` with my class `SequenceGenerator(Sequence)` and pass it to the `fit_generator`, but the `fit_generator` raised an error `ValueError`

Here is my custom class

import os
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import Sequence
from batchGenerator import BatchGenerator

from settings import  batch_size, train_folder, test_folder

```
class SequenceGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, batches_folder):
        self.batch_generator = BatchGenerator(folder_name=batches_folder)      
        self.names = [f for f in os.listdir(batches_folder) if f.lower().endswith('.jpg')]

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.names) / float(batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        print('Getting a bacth{0}'.format(idx))
        [X_batch, Y_batch] = self.batch_generator.load_batch_from_disk(idx)
        return X_batch, Y_batch


def train_seq_genenrator():
    return SequenceGenerator(train_folder)


def test_seq_generator():
    return SequenceGenerator(test_folder)
```

and in jupyter notebook, I imported the following

```
from sequenceGenerator import train_seq_genenrator, test_seq_generator
```

finally here you are the fit_generator call

```
history = new_model.fit_generator(train_seq_genenrator()
                        , steps_per_epoch=num_train_samples // batch_size                        
                        , validation_data=test_seq_generator()
                        , validation_steps=num_test_samples // batch_size
                        , epochs=epochs
                        , shuffle=True)
```

I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-347bef86c8c0> in <module>()
      4                         , validation_steps=num_test_samples // batch_size
      5                         , epochs=epochs
----> 6                         , shuffle=True)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1759         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1760         shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1761         initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1762 
   1763   def evaluate_generator(self,

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    121             '`validation_data` should be a tuple '
    122             '`(val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)` '
--> 123             'or `(val_x, val_y)`. Found: ' + str(validation_data))
    124       val_x, val_y, val_sample_weights = model._standardize_user_data(
    125           val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)

ValueError: `validation_data` should be a tuple `(val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight)` or `(val_x, val_y)`. Found: <sequenceGenerator.SequenceGenerator object at 0x000001DCB58259B0>
```

I don't know why this happens, however this found in https://keras.io/models/sequential/

**validation_data**: This can be either

- a generator or a Sequence object for the validation data
- tuple (x_val, y_val)
- tuple (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights)

Comment: What is your keras version?

Comment: I would also try instantiating a sequence generator object when passing it to fit_generator(); rather than call it as a function that returns a sequence generator

Comment: keras version is 2.2.0 
I tried to instantiate a Sequence generator while calling fit_generator, it raised the same error.